# Why are the elements of my numpy array being floor divided?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

so I have to write a function which normalises the data in a numpy array using the formula: *(x - mean) / (max - min)*. The values of mean and standard_deviation are correct but when I divide by standard_deviation the values of arr all go to zero. I seems to be floor dividing but I don't know why. I have tried using np.divide instead of '/' but the same thing happens. I have included the types and values of the variables that I get when I use my data set in comments. I think the problem lies with the standard_deviation variable because if I use a regular int (e.g. 5) in it's place, it works correctly and the values are non-zero values of type numpy.ndarray. Thanks for the help! :)

```
def normalise (arr):
    total = 0       

    for i in arr:
        total += arr[i] 
    
    mean = total/arr.size                            # type numpy.ndarray value 262.5
    standard_deviation = np.amax(arr) - np.amin(arr) # type numpy.int64   value 525 

    arr_normalised = np.copy(arr)
    
    for i in arr_normalised:        
        arr_minus_mean = arr_normalised[i] - mean    # numpy.ndarray
        arr_normalised[i] = arr_minus_mean / standard_deviation     # works with '5' in place of standard_deviation
    
    return arr_normalised
```

Comment: what version of python and numpy are you using?
For me it converts automatically:


>>> np.int64(8) / np.int64(5)
1.6
>>> type(np.int64(8) / np.int64(5))
<class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.3 and numpy 1.19.2

Answer (score 1):

By the look of your program, I think the problem is you're trying to access the list incorrectly by using an array element as an index.

```
for i in arr:
    total += arr[i]
```

Could you please check if the below works for you?

```
def normalise(arr):
    total = 0

    for i in arr:
        total += i

    mean = total / arr.size  # type numpy.ndarray value 262.5
    standard_deviation = np.amax(arr) - np.amin(arr)  # type numpy.int64   value 525

    arr_normalised = np.copy(arr)

    for i in arr_normalised:
        arr_minus_mean = arr_normalised - mean  # numpy.ndarray
        arr_normalised = arr_minus_mean / standard_deviation  # works with '5' in place of standard_deviation

    return arr_normalised
```

Comment: total is meant to be the sum of all the array values. I don't think total += i  would not achieve this.

Comment: You were right! Sorry I doubted you :) I program in C usually, java sometimes. I was indexing like I would have in those languages. I had no idea it was done this way in python. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check *dtype* of your array. If it is *int* then no surprise that any computed
value is cast just to *int* (rounded down).

## Edit

Assuming that the source array is a *Numpy* array, you can
write the normalization function much more concise way:

```
def normalise(arr):
    return (arr - arr.mean()) / (arr.max() - arr.min())
```

To test it, take as source: `a = np.arange(20)` and call:

```
result = normalise(a)
```

The result is:

```
array([-0.5       , -0.4473684 , -0.39473686, -0.34210527, -0.28947368,
       -0.23684211, -0.18421052, -0.13157895, -0.07894737, -0.02631579,
        0.02631579,  0.07894737,  0.13157895,  0.18421052,  0.23684211,
        0.28947368,  0.34210527,  0.39473686,  0.4473684 ,  0.5       ],
      dtype=float32)
```

Since *mean()* by default returns **float** result, even for *int* source
array, the final result is also of *float* type, even without explicit
casting.

Or if you have a plain, *pythonic* list: `aa = list(range(20))`,
you can call:

```
result = normalise(np.array(aa))
```

(result the same).

Comment: it is int64. So should I begin by casting the whole array to float?

Comment: When you create this array, either pass *dtype='f'* or append *.astype('f')*.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined by Afif Al Mamun, I was incorrectly indexing my array. I was indexing with an array element rather than with the indexing variable i.